# Weblogic12c deployment EJB ambiguous error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, ejb, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy the application in Weblogic 12c. During deployment, I'm getting the below error

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: weblogic.application.naming.ReferenceResolutionException: [J2EE:160092]Error: The ejb-link "BeanClass" declared in the ejb-ref or ejb-local-ref "...BeanClassService/beanClass" in the module "....EJB.jar" is ambiguous. Qualify this ejb-link to remove the ambiguity.
```

Code:

*IBeanClass.java*

```
@Local

public interface IBeanClass {}
```

*BeanClass.java*

```
@Stateless(name = "BeanClass")

@PermitAll

public class BeanClass implements IBeanClass { ...... }
```

*IBeanClassService.java*

```
@Local

public interface IBeanClassService { ......... }
```

*BeanClassService.java*

```
@Stateless(name = "BeanClassService")

public class BeanClassService implements IBeanClassService {

@EJB(beanName = "BeanClass")

private IBeanClassService beanclass;

... }
```

I'm making a call to the EJB from the web application project:

*ClientClass.java*

```
public class ClientClass{ ....

@EJB(beanName = "BeanClassService")

private IBeanClassService beanclass;

..... }
```

The code was working fine in weblogic10 but now in weblogic 12 exception occurs. Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you post your weblogic-ejb-jar.xml/application.xml, specifically the `<ejb-ref>` section? The docs for Weblogic 12 also include an updated example: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24972/examples.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response. In ejb-jar.xml, we do not have any entries since we use annotations only. We have used \@EJB, \@Local,\@Stateless annotations in our code as shown in the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

`BeanClass` is not an `IBeanClassService`, so even by basic java convention, you cannot assign a `IBeanClass` object to that variable there, let alone inject an EJB into that spot. What you should have is

```
  @EJB(beanName = "BeanClass")

  private IBeanClass beanclass;
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem the solution was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>bo.sigep.modulo</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduloSigep-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

in the war pom maven 
the key is provided
regards