# Weblogic12C Issues EJB Remote

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic

I´ve been facing an issue with weblogic 12c and EJB Remote. I´ve read a lot about it but in vain.
My App works properly on weblogic 10.3.3 and I need to move to weblogic 12c, when I deploy I got this error:

```
Caused by: weblogic.application.naming.ReferenceResolutionException: [J2EE:160199]Error resolving ejb-ref "br.com.gvt.sgr.service.impl.SgrServiceBean/sgrDAO" from module "sgr-web.war" of application "sgr-ear". The ejb-ref does not have an ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target bean has not been specified. Attempts to automatically link the ejb-ref to its target bean failed because multiple EJBs in the application were found to implement the "br.com.gvt.sgr.dao.SgrDAO" interface, including sgr-web.war/SgrDaoImpl, sgr-persistence.jar/SgrDaoImpl. Specify a qualified ejb-link for this ejb-ref to indicate which EJB is the target of this ejb-ref.
```

My Interface is:

```
@Local
@Remote
public interface SgrDAO {
}
```

And my Implementation is:

```
@Stateless
public class SgrDaoImpl implements SgrDAO { }
```

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: there is more info in the descriptor ejb-jar.xml ?

Comment: There is nothing on my ejb-jar.xml

Comment: Not the exact same question but viewing this and the related answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282983/weblogic12c-deployment-ejb-ambiguous-error

Comment: please add how are you injecting the ejb in the client

Comment: I am injecting this way:  `@Stateless(mappedName = "sgrService")
public class SgrServiceBean implements SgrService {  @EJB
 private SgrDAO sgrDAO;`

Comment: @castling This link didn´t help me ...